# Is this multiplayer/servers still alive?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-portable-ops, metal-gear-solid-portable-ops-plus

In Metal Gear Solid: Portable Ops/PO+, is the multiplayer still alive? Are people playing it and are the the servers still up?

Comment: If you downvote, what can I improve?

Comment: I imagine you caused someone to revisit the bitter memory of MGO dying with each iteration.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc Peace Walker (at least from my PS3 experiences with the Legacy Collection), is still alive with I've seen around 30-80 people on the Global remaining server. Surprised there is very little latency.

Comment: Sorry, Peace Walker must still be alive because it is the most recent game to have that feature. Konami's policy may be that they shut down the last iteration of MGO shortly after the new one comes out. I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they aren't. Konami has historically only hosted the multiplayer component of the MGS games that have them for a limited time before shutting it down. MGS4's iteration of Metal Gear Online is also gone for good. If you want to play Metal Gear Online again, you can still play Peace Walker online because it is the newest iteration of MGO, so it hasn't been shut down yet. Otherwise, you'll have to buy MGSV: The Phantom Pain and wait until October when MGO is released again... just be sure not to wait too long.